# is there a command line way of getting the git module folder?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Lets say I have a simple directory setup like this:

```
top-level/
   |-- .git/
   |     |-- modules/
   |          |-- level2
   |--level2/
```

Where top-level is a git repo and level2 is a submodule inside top-level. What I want is when I am inside level2 I want to be able to print my .git folder - which is: `/home/.../top-level/.git/modules/level2` or `../.git/modules/level2` (I don't mind relative paths).

For this simple example I can hard code it - but I want a general way of finding this without having to write some script to search up folders until I find the `.git` directory.

I found: `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` which gets me "half way" but from there I still don't know the generalised path to my repo (i.e. I won't know how deep my submodule might be...

Comment: `git rev-parse --git-dir`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+find+%22.git%22+directory

Comment: ah, I was close - but my search was a bit off thanks all, closing as is a dup